# How to upload program to STC 51 in OS X

Tags: macos, sdcc

I used Arduino IDE to program Arduino. But now I have a develop board with STC(51). I have no idea about how to program it in OSX. I found there has a lot of GUI tools in the Windows, but it's hard to find some for OSX.

I found some information about it needs to install "sdcc". But looks like it can't do any upload.

I'm a web developer, it's fine to use command line. But I don't know what tool I need for this task basically. It's better show me an example how to use those tools.

BTW: I don't want to use VM to run Windows. And I like coding in Sublime instead of other IDE.

**EDIT:**

Thanks baf give me information about [stcdude](https://github.com/nekromant/stcdude). But I can't get it work.

I found another one in the issue of stcdude that's [stcgal](https://github.com/grigorig/stcgal). But doesn't works for me for now.

So far, I can use [sdcc](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) compile codes and use [srecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) to convert ihx to bin. But I have to upload it via official Win GUI tool.

BTW: Even though I'm Chinese and saw a lot of bad Chinese websites, but I shocked by the official site of STC and their documents. Thanks those people still write the open source tool for us.

I found this http://www.stcisp.com/mcuisp_stc15f_code_c.html I thought it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you any details, because I don't work with your chip. However I use `sdcc` on OS X. It is a C compiler. You will need it if you want to write programs for your chip using C language.

For programming your microcontroler (uploading compiled program) your only chance may be [stcdude](http://ncrmnt.org/wp/2012/10/01/stcdude-0-1-rc1-is-here/). I looked at its code and I think it should work on mac. You will have to install [lua](http://www.lua.org/home.html) first, if you want to compile it.